# JMeter Javascript language not available for JSR223 Sampler and WebDriver Sampler

Tags: javascript, selenium, jmeter

I'm trying to use Selenium Webdriver Sampler in J-Meter.

Started following tutorials but in the script language dropdown in sampler screen, there is no option for javascript and i can't even run the default/example code.

Am I missing something?
All tutorials seem very simple and don't have any step regarding javascript.

I'm using J-meter 5.3

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. All tutorials seem to be kind of outdated as the [latest Java doesn't come with JavaScript engine](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

So you have 2 options:

1. Downgrade your Java to the version which still has this [Nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) engine (minimum Java version required to run [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) is [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/))
2. Consider using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the problem.