# Jmeter - Javascript not showing up in beanshell preProcessor

Tags: jmeter

[image]

I just installed JMeter on a new computer. On this computer, I don't see JS, and it's saying engine not found. I couldn't find any specific answer to why it's not showing up. Is there something else I need to install?

Comment: Might be useful to mention versions of stuff you are using. Does this help: [JMeter Javascript language not available for JSR223 Sampler and WebDriver Sampler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64910822/3124333)

Answer (score 0):

[Nashorn JavaScript Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine)) which was providing JavaScript language support for the JSR223 Test Elements [has been removed from Java 15 and later](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/372) so the options are in:

1. Downgrade to a previous JRE version where the Nashorn engine is still there, the minimum Java version for running latest [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html) is [Java 8](http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3)
2. Consider using [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) runtime which comes with JavaScript support bundled
3. Consider migrating to Groovy [as it's recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) and [it has the best performance comparing to other scripting options in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/).