# Why isn't JMeter saving some requests statistics on non-GUI mode?

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing some tests using JMeter but it seems that when running the test on GUI mode, some HTTPs requests response statistics can be seen via listeners but, when running the same test on non-GUI mode the same responses aren't saved in the jtl file and thus aren't shown in listeners when loading the jtl file on GUI-mode.

After running the test on GUI mode:

[Results after running test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltbWN.png)

And then, running the same test but on non-GUI mode:

Command:

`path/to/jmeter -n -t path/to/test.jmx -l path/to/results.jtl -j path/to/logfile.log -JnumUsers=10 -Jjmeterengine.force.system.exit=true -Dnashorn.args=--no-deprecation-warning`

[Results after loading the jtl file into a listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEbj4.png)

You can see that the /buscarAvaliacaoAluno and /alterarAvaliacaoAluno responses aren't there anymore.

**edit with error in log**

It seems that it says that it can't find the javascript engine used by a postprocessor

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64910822/jmeter-javascript-language-not-available-for-jsr223-sampler-and-webdriver-sample) I understood that if I'm using java 11 or above, using javascript shouldn't work, but when running `java -version` I get "openjdk version "1.8.0_292" and `echo ${JAVA_HOME}` I get /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91

javax.script.ScriptException: Cannot find engine named: 'javascript', ensure you set language field in JSR223 Test Element: Pega id's questionários
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.getScriptEngine(JSR223TestElement.java:101) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:940) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:572) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]

Answer (score 0):

We cannot provide a comprehensive response without seeing the test plan, the full listener output and the jmeter.log file

If you don't see a sampler result in the .jtl file most probably it hasn't been executed and there could be various reasons for not executing the sampler.

1. You're looking into old results. Given you provide number of users as 50 I would expect at least 50 sampler results and you have only 10. Try adding [`-f` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) to your JMeter startup script so it would overwrite the existing .jtl file with the new data
2. You have logic controllers like [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) for conditionally executing your `/buscarAvaliacaoAluno` and `/alterarAvaliacaoAluno` and the condition is not met
3. You have "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" other than `Continue` in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) so your test fails somewhere before these samplers and hence they are not being executed

   [image]
4. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1) Indeed the command I posted had 50 as numUsers, but that was a mistake and I edited it to the right amount that produced the samples as 10. 2) I do have If controllers in my test plan but, as I have a csv file with users, the same first 10 users are used everytime both by GUI non-GUI mode so the test plan shouldn't have different responses when running on the same users. Thought it might be related to the log level and tryed the -LDEBUG on the command as well but that didnt work.